# How do I record audio on mobile devices for a website?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, audio

I'm writing a web app to process some audio input. It seems like AudioContext and webkitAudioContext (http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html), aren't supported on mobile platforms (i.e. Safari), and file upload seems to only allow access to the camera roll (as opposed for voice memos or other audio files). How can I get audio from a mobile device to a website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), however it's availability is not perfect yet, see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream).